# Как имитировать событие 'change keyup'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имею код, которые срабатывает на событие `on('change keyup'`. Нужно имитировать это событие, чтобы запустить этот код. Пробовала через триггер, понимаю, что он должен работать в связке с `bind`, но и вызов через него событие не видит. Да и менять EventListener не хотелось бы совсем. Есть ли возможность имитировать событие нажатия на клавиши?

```js
$('#foo').on('change keyup', function(){
  alert('Произошло событие change keyup')
});

window.onload = function(e){     
  function writeText(){
    $('#foo').trigger('change keyup');
  }
  setTimeout(writeText, 500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="foo" value="123">
```

Comment: `$('#foo').on('keyup', function(){});` в таком виде подходит (происходит при отпускании кнопки)? Так же есть `$('#foo').on('input', function(){});` происходит при вводе любого значения в `input`

Comment: Нет, мне бы не хотелось менять код со слушателем события

Comment: чтото не пойму....тоже самое только на  `EventListener`?

Comment: Мне нужно не нажимая физически кнопку вызвать это событие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно одно событие в trigger передавать. Так работает:

```js
$('#foo').on('change keyup', function(){
  alert('Произошло событие change keyup')
});

window.onload = function(e){     
  function writeText(){
    $('#foo').trigger('change');
  }
  setTimeout(writeText, 500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="foo" value="123">
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет такого события `'change keyup'`, есть два события `'change'` и `'keyup'`, которые вы просто определили одновременно в конструкции `on`; и в `trigger` их вызывать следует отдельно, например:

```js
$('#foo').on('change keyup', function(){
  alert('Произошло событие change keyup')
});

window.onload = function(e){     
  function writeText(){
    $('#foo').trigger('change'); // тут вызываем или change или keyup
  }
  setTimeout(writeText, 500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="foo" value="123">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inp").trigger({type: 'input', which: 13, keyCode: 13});
});

$("#inp").on('input',function(){
  alert("123");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">test</button>
<input type="text" id="inp" />
```

Comment: нужно имитировать событие не нажимая на кнопку

Comment: @kizoso хорошо, а когда тогда оно должно происходить? При загрузке странички?

Comment: да, при загрузке

Comment: @kizoso поправил